# How can I filter without redundant display to combobox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

hmm this is my problem, How can I prevent double display in my Combobox if i have a datatable
"Student" with column "Section" inside is BE701P, BE101P, BE701P, BE701P, BE101P.
I want to display only to combobox the "BE701P and BE101P" like this preventing redundant display, is it possible?

```
   Private Sub section()
    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT [section] FROM student where username like'" & Administrator.lblusername.Text & "%' ")
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        cmbsection.ValueMember = "section"
        cmbsection.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        cmbsection.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

it will display all data into combobox and makes redundant display. as i want to prevent redundancy. I would be very glad to any suggestions.

Comment: if I select "BE701P" in combobox, all who have "BE701P inside the database will display to datagridview."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `DISTINCT` in your sql query like:

```
 Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT DISTINCT [section] FROM student 
 where username like'" &   Administrator.lblusername.Text & "%' ")
```

See link [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) for mysql examples (although you did not specify your DBMS).

Comment: sorry i loss internet, but it work! :D, I dont know about DISTINCT :) but really thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DataTable from the default DataView of your DataTable that show distinct records only. The advantage of using this approach is that you can keep all records in your original DataTable (which may be used for some other binding). Also note that this is a client-side operation, so you can save your server some processing effort if there are many clients doing this.

The syntax would be something like:

```
 ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.ToTable(True, {"section"})
```